# How do you make widgets take up all space proportionally when the window is resized?

Tags: python, tkinter

When

```
window.resizable(True, True)
```

and you maximize the window, you get the following:

[image: resized_window]

As you can see, the widigets **do not take up the remaining space**.

### Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()

f1 = tk.Frame(win, background = 'yellow', width = '10', height = '20')
f2 = tk.Frame(win, background = 'purple', width = '10', height = '20')

f1.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = 'nsew')
f2.grid(column = 1, row = 0, sticky = 'nsew')

win.mainloop()
```

To solve this, I've **added to the code** the following:

```
win.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
win.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)

win.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
win.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)

win.mainloop()
```

Unfortunately, **it did not work.** The widgets did get bigger, but not enough to fill up all the remaining space, which is colored grey.

[image: failed_solution]

### Question:

How would you make the widgets **take up all the remaining space proportionally**? I mean, If *widget_one* is three times the size of *widget_two*, when you resize the window, you use up all the space in the resized window. Thus, ***widget_one* is three times *widget_two* remains true and both widgets fill up the remaining space.**

Something like this:

[image: desired]

That is, *without unfilled* grey parts of the resized window.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. It's not searchable or copyable, and the visually impaired won't be able to see it at all. Take the time to create a proper [mcve].

Comment: @BryanOakley Please give me a minute.

Comment: @BryanOakley Is it clear now?

Comment: If it's not clear, please let me know. I'll modify as needed.

Comment: I think this webpage covers this: https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/root-resize.html

Comment: You coded for row 1 to have weight, but everything is on row 0. Might not be your problem - I can't remember if non-existent rows use weight. It's worth a shot to get rid of that line, though.

Comment: Remove `win.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you've given a weight of `1` to both row 1 and row 2. When you resize the window, the extra space will be allocated equally to both rows. If you don't want half of the window to remain gray, don't give that second row a weight. If you remove that statement, all extra space will be allocated only to the first row.

Comment: Yes, It works. Although when I get rid of *sticky = 'nsew'*,  it doesn't. Could you tell me why?

Comment: @Nameless: without `sticky`, the widget keeps it's preferred size rather than "sticking" to the sides of the space allocated to it.

Comment: Is the preferred size random, or Is it defined by options width and height?

Comment: @Nameless: it's not random. It's based on the width and height for widgets that have a width and height attribute, and also the width and height of a widget's children.